# Passing type to SplObserver update method

Tags: php, unit-testing, observer-pattern, mockery

I have a state object that extends a base abstract class that implements SplSubject.

This state is then passed to the observers notify method however - my unit tests and IDE complain over type involved.

```
abstract class TQ_Type implements \SplObserver
{
    public function update(TQ_State $tq_state)
    {
       ...
    }
}

abstract class TQ_State implements \SplSubject
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->observers = new SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function attach(TQ_Type $observer)
    {
        $this->observers->attach($observer);
    }

    public function detach(TQ_Type $observer)
    {
        $this->observers->detach($observer);
    }

    public function notify()
    {
        foreach ($this->observers as $observer)
        {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }
}
```

The following test yields: PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of TQ_State::attach() must be compatible with SplSubject::attach(SplObserver $SplObserver)

```
class TQTypeStandardAppealTest extends PHGUnit_Internal
{
    private $under_test;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->under_test =  new TQ_Type_StandardAppeal();
    }

    public function test_pending_standard_appeal_tq_approval_hits_states_notify_method()
    {
        $state = Mockery::mock('TQ_State_Pending')->makePartial();
        $state->shouldReceive('get_event')
            ->withNoArgs()
            ->andReturn('Approve');
        $this->under_test->update($state);
    }
}
```

I derive from these and those derived classes are the subject of the unit tests...

Is this an issue where mockery is not honouring the hierarchy of the object it is mocking

NB I have used a partial mock here as the actual mock returns a Mockery\CompositeExpectation but I'll deal with that later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Derp on my behalf.

Plain and simple these must respect the contracts of the interface so they must have SplObserver and SplSubject. Any further requirement to restrict the ability of on object not of the correct type to trigger the update method of an observer must be handled within that method.